# Anyone get DOOM 3 audio working properly with Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: 10.04, sound, games

The audio configuration must have changed from 9.10 to 10.04, because audio no longer seems to work with DOOM 3. This was the suggested way to run DOOM 3 before, and it worked fine:

```
doom3 +set s_alsa_pcm plughw:0
```

However, DOOM 3 is completely silent after I upgraded to Ubuntu 10.04. Has anyone gotten the audio for DOOM 3 to work in Lucid Lynx?

Edit: Here's some potentially useful console output:

```
------------------------------------
dlopen(libasound.so.2)
asoundlib version: 1.0.22
Alsa is available
------ Alsa Sound Initialization -----
snd_pcm_open SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK 'plughw:0' failed: Device or resource busy
dlclose
WARNING: sound subsystem disabled
```

Edit2: Well, it seems that DOOM 3 is unable to share, like other applications, so closing
Rhythmbox and Chrome and anything else that shows up in Sound Preferences under the
Applications tab worked. I would like to get it to play nice like everything else, but
that may be too much to ask. If someone can come up with a solution that causes DOOM 3 to
coexists peacefully with other applications would constitute an accepted answer. It sucks
to have to close everything else first.

Comment: Sadly Doom III stopped working for me after upgrading to 10.04 :/

Answer (score 2):

Try change the driver to OSS, perhaps like this (sorry I can't verify this command atm):

```
doom3 +set s_driver oss
```

Also check that nothing else is using the sound card, like a music player?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look here: [PulseAudio - Perfect Setup #Quake3](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/PerfectSetup#RTCWEnemyTerritoryTrueCombatEliteQuake3)

Answer (score 1):

Try installing the **libsdl1.2debian-alsa** package.

Answer (score 1):

To get sound working in quake4 (same engine as doom3), I had to combine the 2 suggestions above:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl1.2debian-alsa

doom3 +set s_driver oss
```